# Iterating through each fold in X_validation operator in rapidminer?

Tags: java, machine-learning, classification, rapidminer, text-classification

I am performing a text categorization task in Rapid miner by integrating Rapid miner in Java. I am using 10-fold cross validation (x_validation operator). I have a requirement to access the samples in test/train splits in each fold ?

I have tried a lot but couldn't iterate through each fold ? i am new to Rapid miner so i am stuck at here....

I appreciate any help (i don't have enough reputation to upload image but it's a simple 10-fold cross validation process which i am accessing through java code)  ...

```
Process process = new Process(new File(filePath));
        XValidation validation =(XValidation) process.getOperator("Validation");

        // how to do this step for each fold seperately as it may only be getting these operators only for first iteration/fold
        Operator naive_bayes = validation.getSubprocess(0).getOperatorByName("Naive Bayes"); 
        Operator apply_model = validation.getSubprocess(1).getOperatorByName("Apply Model");

        IOContainer container = process.run();

        IOObject train_data = naive_bayes_weka.getOutputPorts().getPortByIndex(0).getAnyDataOrNull();
        IOObject test_data = naive_bayes_weka.getInputPorts().getPortByIndex(1).getAnyDataOrNull();
```

Comment: Can you provide more details about how you are calling RapidMiner from Java?

Comment: @awchisholm i have created a process in the rapidminer with 10-fold cross validation operator and calling it from my java programe. I have added teh code which may give a clue ...

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you won't need to rebuild the process control structure. Just add a "Store" operator to your process and reload the content wherever you need it. A direct access to intermediary results is not available unless you would not want to modify all operator classes used for your processes.